# Pattern matching on hmatrix Vector type in haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, hmatrix

That question sounds trivial but I really can't find anything helping me on how to deal with it. 
Here's a simple example to reproduce that on Haskell :

```
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra.HMatrix
madd :: Double -> Vector Double -> Vector Double
madd a v = a + v
```

when I load this it complains

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Double’
              with actual type ‘Vector Double’
```

it thinks v is Double while it should be Vector Double, how can I force it in the pattern match to be so ?

please :
I need to match the arguments, not just assign to a lambda function.

Comment: No, it thinks `a` should be a `Vector Double`, and you specify it as a `Double`. Note that in Haskell, the two operands of the `+` should be the same, and that Haskell has no subclassing or implicit type casts.

Comment: You can use `cmap (+a) v`.

Comment: How is this question about pattern matching? You're not doing any pattern matching here. If the real use case is more tricky than `madd a v = a + v` (which by the way is just a complicated way of writing `madd = (+)`), you should perhaps explain what the real use case is.

Comment: it works ... more elaboratively `cmap (\x -> x+a) v`  because thie other syntax gets me confused  .. But why ? Do I need cmap always in order to d operations on hmatrix vectors !

Comment: Well, you can certainly add vectors to vectors using `+` directly, but scalars are not vectors (no matter what Matlab et al. would have you believe). As I already commented in that other question, Haskell really doesn't lend itself well to an array-based workflow. This is somewhat _by design_: we like to give everything the type that it's _conceptually represents_, not say “oh well, everything is an array/vector/matrix/tensor/numberthingy”.

Comment: @leftaroundabout the question is about pattern matching. I need the arguments with the function. In this example `v` doesn't match the `Vector Double` which is confusing and I can't wrap my head around it !

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the full error message `In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘v’
      In the expression: a + v
      In an equation for ‘madd’: madd a v = a + v` seems concerned about `v` not `a`

Comment: Are you sure you want to add a number to an _array_? When Matlab does something like that, it usually means the array is just a poor man's representation of a _function_ (sampled in some way). Why not just represent it as a function then? — Also: are you sure you've understood what  pattern matching is? It seems you're using the term to mean _type matching_, but that's something quite different.